# Android thread exception

Tags: android, multithreading, exception

I have a program that works with multiple threads. 
For each I set uncaught exception handler `th.setUncaughtExceptionHandler (new AppExceptionInterloper ())`, but it displays `"thread exiting with uncaught exception (group = 0x4001d800)"` as a localized problem. Why it appears at the log and not in the class AppExceptionInterloper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same error i have got just now. You must have forgotten to catch the ecxeption in any try-catch like Arrayindexoutofbound or JSONecxeption like wise. I have used the array and got the JSON as the result from the webservice. I forgot to put the JSONEcxeption in it.when i caught it.

When you see the stack trace you will find the "**Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException**" or some thing like another exception in your case. Do catch it. You will get your code run.